# Java Serialization with object input/output stream

Tags: java

In java, we are serializing the objects i.e. object state  over network using serializable marker interface and object streams(serilaze and deseriaze). But we are having a different streams to write the object state.why we are marked the serialization for that object?.

Comment: What are you talking about? I honestly can't understand what you're trying to ask.

Comment: I don't think you serialize objects using `Serializable` marker `interface` in Java. It just tells that the object is eligible for serialization.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, you need to read about [Java Serialization](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/) to understand its concepts, and then proceed.

The crux here is that this (ObjectInput/OutputStream) is the mechanism that Java uses for object serialization. You are, however, free to implement your own serialization mechanism (such as serializing as XML files).

Answer (score 1):

- a `FileInputstream` is a stream , so you are using streams...
- a stream refers to the fact that there is a producer and consumer of information, and that the info is flowing in one way.  Wether the source is a file or object, a stream is still a stream.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your question: yes, you are using streams. ObjectInputStream, ObjectOutputStream for reading/writing data in the network connection, and FileInputStream, FileOutputStream for reading/writing data from files.

The object you're passing to the Object Streams needs to be serializable.